# Good way to place node text next to node (TikZ-library `graphs`)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-graphs

I want to create graphs with `\usetikzlibrary{graphs}`. By default, I would like filled black dots as nodes and the node name next to it.

So far, my best solution is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [empty nodes, % remove node text
            no placement, nodes={ 
                circle, draw, fill=black,
                inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                minimum size=2mm
            }
    ] {
        % manually specify node text
        1[label=left:\(1\), x=0, y=-1]
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Is there a nicer / more intuitive solution to my problem?**

Comment: Do you still want to specify the position of the label? Or should it just be the same? They might be covered by the edges eventually.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel It would be nice if I could specify the position of the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`\tikzgraphnodetext` and variants](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#%5Ctikzgraphnodetext) to access the values of `<name>` and `<text>` in the graphs syntax

```
<name>/<text> [<options>]
```

Using

```
label={\tikzgraphnodetext:\(\tikzgraphnodename\)}
```

as part of your `nodes` allows you to write `1/left` instead. You could also use something like `1 left` with a style that splits the `\tikzgraphnodename` at the   but that would mean you always need to use `1 left` if you want to reference it.

This way, you can just use the `1`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\graph [
  empty nodes, % remove node text
  no placement,
  nodes={
    circle, draw, fill=black,
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
    minimum size=2mm,
    label={\tikzgraphnodetext:\(\tikzgraphnodename\)}
  }
] {
    1/left        [x=0, y=-1],
    2/right       [x=1, y=-1],
    3/below right [x=0, y= 0],
    4/above right [x=1, y= 0];
    1 -> {2, 3[> bend left]}
      -> 4
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If I use your suggestion, I get errors of the form `File ended while scanning for definition of \tikz@label@angle`. Strangely this still compiles.

Comment: What kind of node names and label directions are you using? Maybe a typo? Maybe some unforeseen intereference? Maybe using `"` (e.g. `"1"/left"`) is necessary because something contains special characters?

Comment: No, I used exactly your example in my bigger project, but as a MWE, it does seem to work. Maybe I have some option which breaks that, sry for that.

Comment: Ok, I found out that your solution clashes with the TikZ library `babel`. Do you know how to fix this? Edit: See `https://tikz.dev/library-babel`.

Comment: The `babel` library adds `\scantokens` to the node text and the `label` key will use this in an `\csname` which creates the error. The easiest workaround would be to use `handle active characters in nodes=false` as an option to the TikZ picture (or `/tikz/handle active characters in nodes=false` as an option to only the `\graph` command).

Comment: @Gargantuar The other option is to use babel without activating active chars (depending on your language, they can be more or less useful now that utf8 encoding is the standard). If you change your example to add your specific babel configuration that is creating the problem, maybe you can have a more specific  answer....